# consulta de dos tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, tablas

Tengo que hacer un sistema de reservas donde no solo se verian las mesas reservadas, si no tambien las no reservadas, al consultar una dia y un turno.

Tengo las tablas: guarda las 6 mesas

| tblMesa |
| --- |
| idmesa PK |
| mesa |

y otra tabla donde se guardan las reservas

| tblReserva |
| --- |
| idreserva PK |
| idmesa |
| nombre |
| fecha |
| turno |
| estado |

Lo que estoy haciendo es una busqueda por fecha y turno y la lista me trae obviamente las reservas de la tabla. Pero quisiera que tambien me traiga las mesas que no estan reservadas, de manera que en la misma tabla ya ponga un boton para cambiar el estado.

actualmente me trae algo asi

| Fecha | Turno | Mesa. | Nombre. | Estado. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2021 | Turno 1 | Mesa 3. | Juan. | . Reservado |
| 01/10/2021 | Turno 1 | Mesa 5. | Ana. | . Reservado |

yo quisiera que en esa consulta se vieran las mesas que no estan reservadas, es decir haciendo match con la tabla de MESA, la cual me indica (en este caso) que hay 6 mesas en total.

| Fecha | Turno | Mesa. | Nombre. | Estado. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2021 | Turno 1 | Mesa 1. | Libre | . Disponible |
| 01/10/2021 | Turno 1 | Mesa 2. | Libre | . Disponible |
| 01/10/2021 | Turno 1 | Mesa 3. | Ana. | . Reservado |
| 01/10/2021 | Turno 1 | Mesa 4. | Libre | . Disponible |
| 01/10/2021 | Turno 1 | Mesa 5. | Ana. | . Reservado |
| 01/10/2021 | Turno 1 | Mesa 6. | Libre | . Disponible |

No se si puede hacer realizado con consulta

intente esto:

```
SELECT b.idmesa, b.mesa, r.nombre, r.fecha, r.idturno 
FROM tblmesa b 
LEFT JOIN tblreservar ON b.idmesa = r.idmesa;
```

y me dio como resultado

| Fecha | Turno | Mesa. | Nombre. | Estado. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2021 | Turno 1 | Mesa 1. | Carlos | . Reservado |
| 02/10/2021 | Turno 2 | Mesa 1. | Maria | . Reservado |
| 03/10/2021 | Turno 3 | Mesa 3. | Ana. | . Reservado |
| NULL | NULL. | Mesa 2. | Libre | . Disponible |
| NULL | NULL. | Mesa 4. | Libre | . Disponible |
| NULL | NULL. | Mesa 5. | Libre | . Disponible |
| NULL | NULL. | Mesa 6. | Libre | . Disponible |

Yo quiero poder filtarlo por fecha y turno, y me apareza asi, con los libre y los reservados.
Peroal ponerle el where me salen solo los reservados del dia. turno y pierdo los nulls de las mesas
Gracias

Comment: Buenas, para consultar 2 tablas a la vez, puedes usar JOIN.

Comment: Da la estructura de tus tablas mesa y reserva

Comment: Los detalles dalos en tu pregunta, que ahi se va a entender mejor, edita tu pregunta y explicate mejor

Comment: Intente con left join,  y aparecen todas las mesas

Select b.idmesa, b.mesa, r.nombre, r.fecha ,r .idturno from tblmesa b left join tblreservar on b.idmesa=r.idmesa;

pero al ponerle el filtro del idturno y fecha  ya no aparecen las mesas sin reserva
solo las que estan reservadas

Comment: podrias agregar a tu pregunta que query intentaste, y cual fue la salida que conseguiste? esto se hace con un left join...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta te devuelve todas las reservas con sus mesas y aquellas mesas que nunca estuvieron reservadas (no están presentes en ninguna reserva).

Para obtener las mesas reservadas y libres de una fecha y un turno particular puedes hacer un `LEFT JOIN` pero con una subquery (en lugar de con la tabla `tblreservar`) que retorna solo las reservas de esa fecha y ese turno:

```
SELECT r.fecha, r.idturno, m.idmesa, m.mesa, 
       CASE WHEN r.nombre IS NULL THEN 'Libre' ELSE r.nombre END AS nombre,
       CASE WHEN r.estado = 1 THEN 'Reservado' ELSE 'Libre' END AS estado
FROM tblmesa m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
           FROM tblreservar
           WHERE fecha = '2021-01-01' AND idturno = 1) AS r on m.idmesa = r.idmesa
```

Si la fecha y el turno son nulos (porque esa mesa no fue reservada en esa ocación), puedes utilizar un `CASE` y en ese caso reemplazarlo por la fecha y el turno que usas para filtrar.

Si quisieras listar todas las fechas y turnos, y para cada uno las mesas reservadas y libres, entonces primero tendrías que utilizar una subquery que te retorne todas las mesas que hay pero por fecha y turno, y luego hacer el `LEFT JOIN` con la tabla `tblreservar`:

```
SELECT rm.fecha, rm.idturno, rm.idmesa, rm.mesa, 
       CASE WHEN r.nombre IS NULL THEN 'Libre' ELSE r.nombre END AS nombre,
       CASE WHEN r.estado = 1 THEN 'Reservado' ELSE 'Libre' END AS estado
FROM (SELECT r.fecha, r.idturno, m.idmesa, m.mesa
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT fecha, idturno FROM tblreservar) r
      CROSS JOIN tblmesa m) AS rm
LEFT JOIN tblreservar AS r on r.fecha = rm.fecha AND r.idturno = rm.idturno AND r.idmesa = rm.idmesa
ORDER BY rm.fecha, rm.idturno, m.idmesa;
```

Comment: ESO ES LO QUE NECESITABA!!!! Muchisimas Gracias!!!!!

Comment: De nada @UserMuralla!!! No olvides seleccionar la respuesta si ha contestado tu pregunta, así la misma queda marcada como respondida.